# Some spaces cut off / deleted in a input field

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

**I have a problem with an input field in a image gallery.**

For example when I type "Greifvogel 1985" in the input field.

There is no search result and when I look at the url it is:

```
http://www.braunheinz.de/gallery-search/?tag=Greifvogel%1985
```

BUT when I type "1985 Greifvogel".  The search is correct an the url is:

```
xxxx.de/?tag=1985%25Greifvogel
```

Before the word "Greifvogel" is the number 25, I think thats the space,
so I tried this in the url:

```
xxxx.de/?tag=Greifvogel%251985
```

25 before 1985 an it is correct.

So my question is, why sometimes the space is right and sometimes cut off.

Comment: Please edit your post with your code so we can more easily and faster, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`%25` is the url encoded version of the space in a url. In other words, a url won't work with a space in it so we encode it in a format that can be transmitted (ASCII text).

Here's a reference for [more information.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)